Foreignkey in cat_id is null with bidirectional oneToMany relationship
This is my Category entity:
@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor

@Setter

@Getter

@Entity

@Table(name = "category")

public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  int id;
    
    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private  String catName;
    @Column(name = "image")
    private  String image;
   
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    
    List<Item> items= new ArrayList<>() ;
}

This is the Item entity:
@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor

@Getter

@Setter

@Entity

@Table(name = "items")

public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private  int id;

    @Column(name = "cat_name")
    private  String categoryNames;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Category category;
}

This is the rest controller:
@RestController

public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;
    
    @PostMapping("/post")
     public void post(@RequestBody CategoryDTO categoryDTO) {
    
        categoryService.saveByDTO(categoryDTO);
        }
}

Service implementation:
public interface CategoryService {

    void add(Category category);
    
    void saveByDTO(CategoryDTO categoryDTO);
}

I didn't find this problem before. Unidirectional mapping doesn't throw foreign key null

Does this answer your question? Foreign-key in tb_child is null with bidirectional one-to-many relationship
